# How can I say the leading value.

Tags: polynomials

I think my question is the same as title, but it is vague. So I will support my question with examples.

### \begin{align}
x^3-7x+6=0\\\Rightarrow (x-1)(x-2)(x+3)=0\\\therefore x=1, 2, -3
\end{align}

The leading coefficient is the coefficient of $x^3$, which is $1$.

I want to know how to call the biggest value, which is $2$.

---

The leading value?

The biggest value?

$\max(x_1, x_2, x_3)$?

Comment: Why not just call it the largest root.

Comment: I searched in dictionaries and some mathematical dictionaries, but I couldn't find it. just THE LARGEST ROOT? oh my god... I thought it has a special name like leading coefficient.

Comment: What if the roots are $-2,0,1$? Do you want the largest (1) or the largest in absolute value (2)? What if the polynomial has complex roots as well?

Comment: the root of a polynomial is just a number, so normally you compare them just as numbers.

Comment: What I want to call is the most rightward value in X-axis. Also, real system.

Comment: People make special names to avoid ambiguity and to shorten long descriptions. Neither of these criteria is the case for "the largest root", so why would you want a special name for it?

Comment: @cr001 I just wondered how mathematicians call 'the largest root'. Now, I realized it doesn't have any special name. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call it the largest root.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little ambiguity in your question.
There is a number $3$ - a (largest) root of the polynomial, and the highest degree of $x$ which determines the degree of the polynomial is also $3$.

choose which one you asked about^)

Comment: Sorry for my idiot question. :( $\\$I edited the example.

Comment: a largest root is still the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what "large" or "leading" means. What is your intention? What does it mean to "lead"? It is in some sense the most positive solution. The solution with most positive real component. But -3 has a larger absolute value.

But what does it mean to 'lead'? I guess that is more of a philosophical, meta-mathematical or even application-specific question.